# Run python TensorFlow code on a Django made website?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, web-frameworks

I want to make a website using entirely python and I want to add code made using the TensorFlow module. The idea is to create a website me and my friends can upload training data too no matter where we are.

I am trying to make a website using python (it must remain entirely in python) so i'm looking at Django for the website. Using Django (or any other framework) can I add code onto the site even if its from TensorFlow such as this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
print(node1, node2)

Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run([node1, node2]))
```

Is what I want possible to do in python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. A web-framework is just that, a framework. You can still write any kind of python code you want in addition to it.

You may need to consider something like a work-queue structure so that pages do not go unresponsive/timeout while long calculations take place though.